# Haskell read type inferences

Tags: haskell

Haskell newbie wants to know why the first 3 were ok but the 4th statement blew up:

```
Prelude> read "5.3" + 5.0                   -- ok
10.3

Prelude> read "5"   + 5                     -- ok
10

Prelude> read "5"   + 5.3                   -- ok
10.3

Prelude> read "5.3" + 5                     -- huh ???
*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
```

I see that :t 5.3 is Fractional whereas 5 is just Num, but both must be returnable from read because the first three commands worked, and (+) should work on any pair of Nums.  What's going on here ?

Comment: You can specify the type explicitely: `(read "5.3" :: Double) + 5`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When the type of a numeric expression is ambiguous, Haskell tries to resolve it first to `Integer`, and then to `Double` (a floating-point number) if that doesn't work. This is because it would be pretty annoying to have to explicitly specify the types for simple arithmetic expressions.

This specific example happened because `5.3` can't be an `Integer` (since `Integer` is not `Fractional`), so it resolved to `Double` in that case. But since `5` can be an `Integer`, and `read "5.3"` can be any type that can be read, it defaulted to `Integer`, and blew up at runtime, since `5.3` isn't a valid `Integer` literal.

If you turn on `-Wall`, you'll be able to see this type defaulting happen; it'll show a warning when it does. (This is typically quite annoying in practice, though, since such defaulting is very common in GHCi.)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Now I see that you can't do (5::Float)+(5::Integer) and that my 4th command resolved to this.  Still, I'm surprised that inference typing doesn't try other branches - e.g. go back and try resolving 5 to something else, at least where built in operators are concerned.

Comment: It can't "go back", because type checking happens before execution.  And the string is only examined by read during execution.